# Call count not working with async function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-asyncio

I have a function that has a decorator `@retry`, which retries the function if a certain Exception happened. I want to test that this function executes the correct amount of times, for which I have the following code which is working:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_redis_failling(mocker):
    sleep_mock = mocker.patch.object(retry, '_sleep')
    with pytest.raises(ConnectionError):
        retry_store_redis()
    assert sleep_mock.call_count == 4

@retry(ConnectionError, initial_wait=2.0, attempts=5)
def retry_store_redis():
    raise ConnectionError()
```

But, if I modify `retry_store_redis()` to be an async function, the return value of `sleep_mock.call_count` is 0.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I think I'm running into the same error.  `call_count` is 0 when using async code.

Comment: @chishaku using pytest `mocker.Mock()` works for me, my problem was the retry code wasn't async compliant (switched to tenacity).

Comment: Since python 3.8, there is an `AsyncMock` which has an `await_count` attribute

Answer (score 2):

So you define "retry" as a function. Then you define a test, then you define some code that uses @retry.

@retry, as a decorator, is being called at import time. So the order of operations is

1. declare retry
2. declare test
3. call retry with retry_store_redis as an argument
4. start your test
5. patch out retry
6. call the function you defined in step 3

so "retry" gets called once (at import time), your mock gets called zero times. To get the behavior you want, (ensuring that retry is actually re-calling the underlying function) I would do

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_redis_failling(mocker):
    fake_function = MagicMock(side_effect=ConnectionError)

    decorated_function = retry(ConnectionError, initial_wait=2.0, attempts=5)(fake_function)

    with pytest.raises(ConnectionError):
        decorated_function()
    assert fake_function.call_count == 4
```

if you wanted to test this as built (instead of a test specifically for the decorator) you would have to mock out the original function inside the decorated function- which would depend on how you implemented the decorator. The default way (without any libraries) means you would have to inspect the "closure" attribute. You can build the object to retain a reference to the original function though, here is an example

```
def wrap(func):
    class Wrapper:
        def __init__(self, func):
            self.func = func

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    return Wrapper(func)


@wrap
def wrapped_func():
  return 42
```

in this scenario, you could patch the wrapped function at `wrapped_func.func`

Comment: The behaviour i want is already defined. 
Initially the test gets called which mocks the retry object _sleep method so i can see how many times it's getting called
After which i call the retry_store_redis, it raises an error which gets catched by retry and repeats itself, after a certain number of calls it exists and i make sure that the number of calls is what i wanted. My trouble comes in when i try to make the retry_store_redis() function async and await it in with pytest.raises(ConnectionError):
After doing that the count returns a 0 instead of the desired 4

Comment: But- you mocked out a decorator, you did NOT mock out the function that the decorated function is trying to call. Worse, you mocked out the decorator after it had already been used.